# Visio 2013: Limit displayed lines in a shape

Tags: scrollbar, overflow, visio, office-2013

## Visio 2013: Create scrollbar for hidden overflow

.

I have a list of over 112 items. Which, is extensive for a simple diagram. I would like to have only 4 lines viewable and have a scroll bar to view the overflow.ties.

e.g.
I have a list of sites that are hosted on each server. To have all the sites for all servers displayed will decrease diagram readability. I need to set the max displayed lines to 4. The rest needs to be hidden. You should be able to view these by using a scroll bar.

This is a common practice in HTML. Hoping to find a way to do this with Visio 2013 also.

For example:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain4.com
--Overflow--
domain5.com
domain6.com
andmanymore.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the filtering in visio, provide already filtered data. ie: fill the list field already with a string, where the domains are separated by CHR(10).
This operation is easier to realise in excel/access/VBA.
I would send a draft, but I don't see a possibility to add attachments to answers.
HTH, otherwise don't hesitate to ask for details.

Comment: Perfect, I was hoping there was some easy way. I'm new to Visio.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have the list of domains in a user defined field.
Now add another field with the following formula mid(prop.yourlist,controls.start,prop.numberOfCharactersToDisplay)
where:
controls.start would be a control added to scroll your list and
prop.numberof.. the number of characters to display.

Insert now the new field to be displayed in your shape. Done.

These formulas will of course truncate your domains at any place in the string. If you want it to show always full lines, you should look for the line breaks (find(char(10), yourList)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the response. First time using this formula mid(). So for 'prop.yourlist' I can call an external spreadsheet, or just list the entire list in that box? The thing is I have 7 different servers each hosting different domains. If I get a list from the spreadsheet then it will need to filter only from the currect webserver. (EXAMPLE> If DomainLocation = 'Webserver01' Add to List).

Comment: I don't know how you are getting your data in the visio file. There are many different ways to do it. So your question is not clear to me. You may want to tell us more about your project.

Comment: I have a list of domains which have information attached to each one. For example, Mydomain.com, location:server01, Description for domain, webmaster, webmaster@email.com, webmaster phone number. From this excel spreadsheet I'd like viso to find all domains from server01 and add them to the list connected to server01 and so forth for servers 1-7. This way I can just update the spreadsheet and the visio chart automatically updates.